# Sending array of strings from client to jersey server

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, jersey

How can I send an array of strings from client to jersey server?
My server method looks like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<User> createUpdateUser(@NotNull @BeanParam User user) {
    siteDao.addUser(user);
    Collection<User> l = siteDao.listSites();
    ArrayList<User> al = new ArrayList<User>(l);
    return al;
}
```

User object contains the array of strings - see below.

My Java Script client method (inside my index.html) to prepare user object to be sent to server looks like this:

```
function getFormUserDetails() {
    var user = {
        servingDates: ['jan','feb']
    }
    return user;
}
```

My ajax call to the server looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#addUserButtonId').on('click touchstart', (event) => {
        var user = getFormUserDetails();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/remote-loader/App/User/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: user, 
            }).done((data, textStatus, xhr) => {
                // some code here
            }).fail((jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                console.log( errorThrown );
            }).always(() => {
            });
        });
    });
```

My `User` class looks like this:

```
public class User /* implements Serializable */ {
    @FormParam("servingDates") 
    private List<String> servingDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public List<String> getServingDates() {
        return servingDates;
    }

    public void setServingDates(List<String> servingDates) {
        this.servingDates = servingDates;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that user object when method createUpdateUser is called by Jersey contains an empty servingDates array.

Comment: Have you already checked that the data is contained inside the objects on the server side? What type of debugging have you done already. This information will help us out in crossing out some possible issues. Also what dependency are you using as your JSON provider?

Comment: You can edit your post. Do not post an update in the answer section

Comment: 1. Remove the BeanParam annotation. 2. Set the content-type header in the client to application/json. 3. Add @Consumes("application/json") on the server side. 4. I haven't used jquery in forever so I'm not sure if it will automatically stringify the object automatically or if you will have to stringify it yourself.

Comment: I followed your steps but I am getting an error inside ajax function. I had to use JSON.stringify() method. The textStatus is just "error". I can't send you the proof from Wireshark that I have applied all three suggestions as "Comment" has limitation on number of chars sent.

Comment: Hello Paul. Hope everything is OK. Can you reply to my last comment please?

Comment: We need more information. There is not enough information to reproduce the problem. And we don't even know the exact problem. Saying there is an error doesn't give us much to work off.

Comment: Hi Paul, what other info you would need. That is all I got from chrome? Any suggestions what I can retrieve from chrome?

Comment: What type of debugging hav you done? Can u see in the browser development tools that the request is going out correctly? Have you tried to log the request on the server side?